# Волновой алгоритм Ли С++

Tags: c++, графы

Я пытаюсь разобраться в волновом алгоритме.Допустим у меня есть такой граф.С такой матрице смежности. Скрин приложил. Как для этого алгоритма написать карту путей

```
int G[V][V] =  {    
   { 0,7,8,0,0,0 } , 
   { 7,0,11,2,0,0 } , 
   { 8,11,0,6,9,0 } , 
   { 0,2,6,0,11,9 } , 
   { 0,0,9,11,0,10 } , 
   { 0,0,0,9,10,0 }  
 } ;
```

[image: Граф]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под "картой путей"?

Comment: что-то типо того что я прикрепил второй фоткой. это с википедии. это карта вроде составляется с помощью двумерного массива или Map

Comment: на карте указан один путь. Плюс, одинаковая цена шага, при переходе в соседнюю клетку. Это слабо связано с графом на первой картинке.

Comment: а можно пример с графом и картой для него, если несложно?

Comment: для него не будет такой карты, как на втором рисунке, особенно учитывая разность весов в ребрах.

Comment: да я не про этот граф. можешь привести любой граф подходящий и показать, как для него карту составить? я уже понял, что веса должны быть равные

Comment: смотри, таблица на второй картинке - это и есть граф :) каждая клеточка - это узел, который связан с 4 или 8 соседями (в зависимости от правил хода. в данном случае с 4, так как нельзя наискосок ходить)

Comment: далее выбираешь любую начальную клетку. И обходишь граф в ширину: а именно берешь все соседние клетки, проставляешь на них номер шага - и рекурсивно проходишься по ним. В итоге поле заполняется числами, пока ты не придешь в выбранную клетку, либо пока не сможешь пройти дальше. После этого проходишь обратно до нулевой клетки и получаешь путь.

Comment: спасибо за пояснение